UIDocumentPickerViewController no longer has delete option on long press
Previously (maybe before iOS 17) UIDocumentPickerViewController had a long press option to delete a file, but this no longer exists.
UIDocumentPickerViewController *picker = [[UIDocumentPickerViewController alloc] initWithDocumentTypes:@[(NSString *)kUTTypeJPEG] inMode:UIDocumentPickerModeOpen];
picker.delegate = self;
picker.directoryURL = ubiquityURL;
picker.presentationController.delegate = self;
[self presentViewController:picker animated:YES completion:nil];

We are having to tell our users to go to the Files app to delete a file from iCloud Drive.
Is there something that I am missing that allows files to be deleted like before?
